# Validate Japanese Email include special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an Email below:
anzai-kt@itec.hankyu-hanshin.co.jp
Now i want to validate it but not working.
this is my regex:

```
$scope.emailParten = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

From: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

Yours doesn't count "-" as a correct character. Generally validating e-mails is more complex, but this should work for most use cases.

This for example:

```
very.“(),:;<>[]”.VERY.“very@\\ "very”.unusual@strange.example.com
```

Is a correct e-mail address, but doesn't get covered by the regular expression in my answer.

If you want to support these weird edge cases try:

```
/^.+@.+\..+$/
```

Source: http://codefool.tumblr.com/post/15288874550/list-of-valid-and-invalid-email-addresses

Comment: I have a phone number with format like: 04-3836-4870. My validate: